# Django messages not working with HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django

I have the following code in Django. Only showing the relevant part

```
    messages.info(request, "Welcome ...")
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Now I dont see the messages in the `'/'` url

How can we do this

Comment: Can you show the view and the template behind the ``\``? Normally it is also a forward slash `/`, not ``\``.

Comment: yes edited the question. The view behind the `/` passes lot of data to the template

Comment: Does your template contain html to [display messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages)?

Comment: @Santhosh: well since we can not see that view, we can not know diagnose the problem...

Comment: Yes, the template has the code to display the message. And the view does not contain anything about messages